# Where to redeem the advertised discount of 50% off from JetBrains WebStorm?

Tags: support, advertising

Not really sure if this is the correct place to ask...

The other day when I was looking at a JetBrains WebStorm  personal license, the price was $69. Today, I saw an Ad on SO from JetBrains offering 50% off a WebStorm personal license. When I clicked on the SO ad, I was taken to the JetBrains' WebStorm page; and upon attempting to purchase the WebStorm personal license, the price was still $69. Where is the 50% off?

Link to Ad Image:
http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/e8ee13ad9cef4f9095bf0fee3ac390d2.png

Link to Ad:
http://engine.adzerk.net/redirect/0/4001/5393/8277/22354eb54d424dc982b0b72e3f68129c/45/1178/6385/634501499984359522?keywords=c%23%2cjavascript%2cvisual-studio-2010%2cjavascriptserializer%2cjavascript-intellisense%2cx-user-registered%2cx-1500plus-rep

Comment: Probably a direct email first to JetBrains, and if that doesn't work to the Team here (see link in the footer).

Comment: I'll send an email to JetBrains; SO should be aware of this type of advertising if it really is misleading. I'd like to think there was a mistake somewhere, though.

Comment: I agree, companies that allow advertising should be kept aware if there is a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm WebStorm Marketing Manager at JetBrains.
Thank you for noticing this mistake and reporting it.
We fixed it.
And by the way we can award you with free WebStorm Personal License if you want to :)
Just drop a note: alexey.korsun at jetbrains.com
Thank you, once more.

Comment: Alexey, was the $69 personal license the already the discounted rate? Or was the 50% off supposed to be an additional 50% off the $69 rate?

Comment: I'm not the sort of person that would use WebStorm, but that's *pretty damn impressive* service.

Answer (score 8):

I handle advertising sales for Stack Exchange. I have reached out to my contact at Jetbrains to look into this further. Please allow me some time to get answers and I'll post them here.

EDIT: For final resolution, see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104217/where-to-redeem-the-advertised-discount-of-50-off-from-jetbrains-webstorm/104735#104735)