# Are ads on Stack Overflow connected to user activity and interests?

Tags: discussion, advertising

My question is regarding the advertising on Stack Overflow. I'm wondering are the ads in somehow connected to the user activity and displayed accordingly or no?

For example if I answer more MongoDB, Backbone questions or I have favorited tags, regarding javascript, will I see more ads about MongoDB and Javascript in general or I will see random ads, based on inside algorithm independent from my profile data?

I'm wondering, because I can't find a pattern in the ads I'm seeing and I want to make sure that there are companies ads that I have never seen.

Comment: I don't think so, I've often Microsoft ads but I'm not a Microsoft user at all.

Comment: I recently found out that I see a lot of different ads, which I haven't seen before and I was wondering is this connected to my reputation change. ( I'm talking about the ads on the right side of the page, the ads in the middle ( which I don't see anymore, because of my reputation ) are google ads, I think! )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Advertising on Stack Overflow is not targeted by direct user activity.

Advertisers have the opportunity to buy advertising on a run of site basis (anywhere we have available inventory) or more detailed targeting such as specific tags or geographic locations.

Using your example above, if you tend to participate most in the MongoDB and Backbone tags, you will see a mix of ads that are targeted directly to those tags, run of site advertising, and our own house ads depending on inventory availability.

Comment: Because it's not immediately clear from Danny's profile or user box here, I'll note that he handles ad sales for the network. [Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104304/152134)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I've updated my profile! :)